# Cordova.exec callback not executed after [self.commandDelegate sendPluginResult ...] - iOS

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova, plugins

I'm updating an app that uses Phonegap 1.x to the newest version.

For some reason, one of the plugins I wrote isn't executing the success/callback functions back in the js side. It's the first plugin I tried so it might actually be a system-wide issue.

**Old version of the plugin** (very simple plugin, just gets some string from the native side):

```
- (void)pushString:(NSMutableArray*)arguments withDict:(NSMutableDictionary*)options {
    NSString * jsCallBack = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SomeClass.successCallBack('%@');", someNativeStringVar];
 //SomeClass.successCallBack exists on the js side
    [self.webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:jsCallBack];
}
```

**New version of the plugin**:

```
-(void)pushString:(CDVInvokedUrlCommand *)command {
    pluginResult = [CDVPluginResult resultWithStatus:CDVCommandStatus_OK messageAsString:someNativeStringVar];
   [self.commandDelegate sendPluginResult:pluginResult callbackId:command.callbackId];
}
```

**Javascript:**

```
function getNativeString(jsCallBack, jsFailCallback)
{
    //Called sometime at the load of the webview
    cordova.exec(jsCallBack, jsFailCallback, "PluginClass", "pushString", []);
}
```

When trying to debug the plugin, I do manage to break inside pushString() so I know it's executing ,but for some reason the callbacks do not. I tried using the old callback version (stringByEvaluating...) with the new Cordova and it causes the failure callback to execute.

Any help towards solving this issue would be appreciated.

Comment: can you post your javascript?

Comment: It's fairly standard, posted it

Comment: I just wanted to see if you updated it too, as you are updating from 1.x, and it used a different syntax then. But it seems ok to me

Comment: try without assigning the pluginResult,  [self.commandDelegate sendPluginResult:[CDVPluginResult resultWithStatus:CDVCommandStatus_OK messageAsString:someNativeStringVar]  callbackId:command.callbackId];

Comment: Any solutions for this?